# article(Noweb) in LyX 2.0.0

Tags: lyx

I've tough luck with running article(Noweb) in LyX 2.0.0. Could someone guide me how to run article(Noweb) in LyX 2.0.0? Sharing an example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? What do you mean by `article(Noewb)`?

Comment: @Sharpie: article(Noweb) is a Document Class where we can include R code.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting. Just kind of a convention here to keep the questions concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example. Save to a .lyx file and open with LyX 2.0. I suspect that you haven't included the Sweave module in Document -> Settings... -> Modules.

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass literate-article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
sweave
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1in
\topmargin 1in
\rightmargin 1in
\bottommargin 1in
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Chunk
<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chunk
rnorm(5)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chunk
@
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chunk

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: @Kevin: Would you like to give me the exact web link of this file. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin: Would you like to give me the exact web link of this file. When I tried to open sweave.lyx, LyX warned me that the package sweave -> latex is missing. Guide me how I can include this package. Thanks

Comment: Do you have R installed?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I do.

Comment: It looks like Sweave.sty can't be found. You could try copying it to one of the directories so that LyX can find it.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Try posting your question to the lyx-users mailing list (http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists). Without a lot more information about your setup (i.e., we don't even know what OS you are using), it's hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this blog post by Yihui Xie will provide a good example and starting point if you are looking to do literate programming with LyX and R:

> http://yihui.name/en/2010/10/how-to-start-using-pgfsweave-in-lyx-in-one-minute/

*Disclaimer: I don't actually use LyX myself*

Comment: This is nice but I'm using LyX 2.0.0 which already have every thing in it.